# Check if user has a custom permission in flow

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a record triggered flow on the `User` Object. That leads to having two user records.

1. User 1: The user record that triggered the flow.
2. User 2: The current user running the flow.

I want to check if the user record that triggered the flow (user 1) has a certain permission but I'm enable to do so since I can only check permissions for the current user (user 2).

[image]

Comment: Can you add more highlight on why your running user and user which has triggered the flow are diffrent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the problem by getting the `Permission Set Assignment` and checking if the returned list is null.

**Get Permission Set**

[image]

**Get Permission Set Assignment**

[image]

**Decision Check**

[image]